# Iteratively add columns of various length to DataFrame

Tags: python, dataframe

I have few categorical columns (description) in my DataFrame `df_churn` which i'd like to convert to numerical values. And of course I'd like to create a lookup table because i will need to convert them back eventually.

The problem is that every column has a different number of categories so appending to `df_categories` is not easy and I cant think of any simple way of do so.

Here is what I have so far. It stops after first column, because of the different length.

```
cat_clmn = ['CLI_REGION','CLI_PROVINCE','CLI_ORIGIN','cli_origin2','cli_origin3', 'ONE_PRD_TYPE_1']

df_categories = pd.DataFrame()

def categorizer(_clmn):
    for clmn in cat_clmn:
        dict_cat = {key: value for value, key in enumerate(df_churn[clmn].unique())}

        df_categories[clmn] = dict_cat.values()
        df_categories[clmn + '_key'] = dict_cat.keys()

        df_churn[clmn + '_CAT'] = df_churn[clmn].map(dict_cat)

categorizer(cat_clmn)
```

Comment: Pandas [categoricals](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html) would automate this kind of thing for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a temporary solution, but I am sure it can be done in a better way.

```
df_CLI_REGION = pd.DataFrame()
df_CLI_PROVINCE = pd.DataFrame()
df_CLI_ORIGIN = pd.DataFrame()
df_cli_origin2 = pd.DataFrame() 
df_cli_origin3 = pd.DataFrame()
df_ONE_PRD_TYPE_1 = pd.DataFrame()

cat_clmn = ['CLI_REGION','CLI_PROVINCE','CLI_ORIGIN','cli_origin2','cli_origin3', 'ONE_PRD_TYPE_1']
df_lst = [df_CLI_REGION,df_CLI_PROVINCE,df_CLI_ORIGIN,df_cli_origin2,df_cli_origin3, df_ONE_PRD_TYPE_1]


def categorizer(_clmn):
    for clmn, df in zip(cat_clmn,df_lst):
        d = {key: value for value, key in enumerate(df_churn[clmn].unique())}
        df[clmn] = d.values()
        df[clmn + '_key'] = d.keys()

        df_churn[clmn + '_CAT'] = df_churn[clmn].map(d)

categorizer(cat_clmn)
```